# MongoDB update/refesh collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a question how to update collection with API call without overwriting exisiting data already saved in DB.
I mean at first load i am loading 400 documents and saved them. On another 
API call API will return 422 so i need to add those 22 to already 400 taht are in DB. how to loop throught DB and add those 22 without touching/modifing already existing 400?

EDIT:

Comment: use a timestamp having a value after the orig. 400 inserts . this assumes your doc has _created_date field on which you can compare and select

Comment: You are saying 22 documents were already added, where are you trying to add them again?

Comment: please see update description of problem

Comment: Are there unique keys that can identify which ones are duplicates? please give some more concrete examples

Comment: yes for example clientID